# Migrating from Cytoscape JS 3.2.22 to 3.3.0: Graph doesn't render and browser window crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, cytoscape.js

I have a node js application that visualises a graph using Cytoscape JS. I wanted to use the new feature of taxi edge style in 3.5.2, but everytime I render the graph the page freezes and crashes after a while with version 3.5.2. Also the CPU usage spikes to ~100%. I use the Cytoscape instance as part of a class.

I have traced it back to the migration from Cytoscape JS 3.2.22 to 3.3.0. But that is all I could find. I examined the changelogs in the Cytoscape JS repo, but couldn't find anything that seemed relevant, except: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/2311. This leads to #2295, the fix there didn't help either. So I guess that was not related either.

```
this.renderedGraph = Cytoscape({
      container: $(`#${graphID}`),


      style: Cytoscape.stylesheet()
        .selector("node")
        .css({
          "content": "data(graphAbbrev)",
          "text-wrap": "wrap",
          "padding": "4px",
          "width": "label",
          "height": "label",
          "text-valign": "center",
          "text-halign": "center",
          "shape": "roundrectangle",
          "background-color": `mapData(weight, 0, ${
            this.maxNodeWeight
          }, #1cb5e0, #000046)`,
          "color": "white"
        })
        .selector("edge")
        .css({
          "line-fill": "linear-gradient",
          "text-margin-x": "20px",
          "text-rotation": "autorotate",
          "label": "data(weight)",
          // "curve-style": "taxi",
          // "taxi-direction": "downward",
          // "taxi-turn": 20,
          // "taxi-turn-min-distance": 5,
          "target-arrow-shape": "triangle",
          "target-arrow-color": `mapData(weight, 0, ${
            this.maxEdgeWeight
          }, #E6DADA, #274046)`,
          "line-color": `mapData(weight, 0, ${
            this.maxEdgeWeight
          }, #E6DADA, #274046)`
        }),
      layout: {
        name: "preset",
        fit: true,
        padding: 30
      },

      elements: {
        nodes: this.nodes,
        edges: this.edges
      }
    });
```

I would expect this to render the usual graph as it does in 3.2.22, but no luck with anything from 3.3.0 and above.